# Convert a row, column value to dict and to a dataframe pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, series

python noob here.

I have a dataframe `people` with `name` and `text` as two columns.

```
  name       text
0 Obama      Obama was the 44th president of the...
1 Trump      Donald J. Trump ran as a republican...
```

and I need to perform some exploratory analysis on `Obama` only.

```
obama= people[people['name'] == 'Obama'].copy()
obama.text

35817    Obama was the 44th president of the unit...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

How do I convert the text to a dict as a new column with keys as words and count of words as value?
*example:*

```
   name       text                                  dictionary
0 Obama      Obama was the 44th president of the... {'Obama':1, 'the':2,...}
```

once done, how do I convert the dictionary to a separate dataframe?
*expected:*

```
   word   count
0  Obama  1
1  the    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Counter` object from the collections module:

```
import collections

people['dictionary'] = people.text.apply(lambda x: dict(collections.Counter(x.split())))
```

To convert one of these dictionaries to a dataframe:

```
dictionary = people['dictionary'][0]
pd.DataFrame(data={'word': dictionary.keys(), 'count': dictionary.values()})
```

Comment: The first portion works like a charm. The second to convert dict to a dataframe continued to give me issue `'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`. I finally resolved it using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient="index")`

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I would expect `people['dictionary'][0]` to yield a dictionary, but sounds like you are getting a pandas Series. Maybe you are using a different version of pandas. You could try using `Dataframe.loc` or `Dataframe.iloc` as referenced [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Comment: Yes, you are right, it indeed was a series and I was baffled having moved from `R`. I thought it is how `pandas` work, but looks like it some specific version. Anyways, the problem for now is resolved, and I am going to try your suggestions as soon as possible.